# How can I tell if a python fabric connection is ready?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, fabric

I have a script that creates AWS instances and uses fabric==2.5.0 to configure them. Here is my problem with using a fabric2 Connection instance in the script:

```
def setup_site(self, ip, name):
    connection = Connection(ip, user='toolman')
    # If I put ipdb here, just continuing it will work.
    # If take the debug line out, it will fail
    # with "NoValidConnectionsError: [Errno None] Unable to connect to port 22 on ..."
    # import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
    connection.put(self.create_setup_file(name), 'setup.yaml')
```

I can just hit 'c' to continue the debugger and everything works fine every time. If I don't have the debugger line in place, the connection.put call fails every time with "NoValidConnectionsError: [Errno None] Unable to connect to port 22 on ...".

The AWS instance it is putting the file to is running (instance.wait_until_running() returns in the code calling setup_site).

Comment: You may need to call `connection.open()` to initialise the connection - http://docs.fabfile.org/en/2.5/api/connection.html#fabric.connection.Connection.open

Comment: I will try that but I don't need to do it with the ipdb interruption happening

Answer (score 2):

If I sleep python for 30s everything works so this issue is probably something not ready in the AWS instance.

`connection.open()` should not be needed but works sometimes probably because it takes time.

I've ended up using the following function in place of the Connection call:

```
def ensure_connection(*connection_args, ensure_connection_timeout=30, **connection_kwargs):
    start = timer()
    while (timer() - start) < ensure_connection_timeout:
        try:
            connection = Connection(*connection_args, **connection_kwargs)
            connection.open()
            return connection
        except NoValidConnectionsError as e:
            connection_error = e
    # noinspection PyUnboundLocalVariable
    raise connection_error
```